# How to use Express with Vue

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, heroku, npm

First time using Node js, Express and Vue.

I have a pomodoro timer website made with vue (not vue-app/vue-cli) which I'm wanting to upload to Heroku. The website works perfectly locally with Webstorm IDE, but can't manage to make it work with Express.

Github link of project: https://github.com/marcelmiro/Pomodoro

This is how my files are organized:

```
+-- node_modules
  -- vue & express modules
+-- scripts
  -- main.css
  -- main.js (where my vue code is)
  -- bundle.js (me testing how to use a webpack. its not being used atm)
+-- assets
  -- all images
+-- index.html
+-- package.json
+-- Procfile
+-- server.js
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use("/scripts", express.static("scripts"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html"));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server connected at:',port);
});
```

So I can manage to load css (although not all css code), but not main.js (where my vue code is). Images are also not loaded.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `index.html` is in your root folder, you just need to tell express to look there;

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server connected at:',port);
});
```

In practice you would want to separate your source code from your production code, but that's a little out of scope for this question.

Comment: So should I replace "app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));" for  "app.use("/scripts", express.static("scripts"));" ?

Comment: Nope, just use it exactly as stated above. You scripts folder is relative to index.html, so you're saying to Express when you hit '/' (ie, any route), serve index.html

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! By the way what did you mean when saying I should separate source code and production code?

Comment: No problem. Separate src and dist folders - so your production ready code is bundled into 'dist' when you're ready to deploy. It's quite involved so I'd recommend following a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j55fHUJqtyw

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vue to create a single page application, you might be using [history mode](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html). In that case, here is a full solution with ssl and http redirects to https:

```js
/* server.js */
const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https')
const http = require('http')
var express = require('express')
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const app = express()
const redirectHttp = express()

/*
 * Redirect http to https
 */
redirectHttp.get("*", (req,res,next) => {
        res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url)
})

// USE HMTL5 History API, allows Vue to handle the routing
const staticFileMiddleware = express.static("./dist");
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
app.use(history({}));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);

http.createServer(redirectHttp).listen(80,()=>{console.log('Listening for http requests...')})

https
  .createServer(
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/cert'),
      ca: fs.readFileSync('path/to/cert'),
    },
    app
  )
  .listen(443, () => {
    console.log('Listening for https requests...')
  })
```

This assumes your dist directory is in the same folder as server.js